# Center a bigger div inside a smaller div with overflow

Tags: html, styles, zooming

I can not find or figure out.

Inside a div with overflow, I put another div with a zoom option.
I like to center the inner div in the outer div when it becomes bigger by zooming but solutions like *margin: 0px auto;* does not work.

```
<div  id="container" style="float:left; overflow:scroll; width:644px; height:702px;">
  <div  id="zoomimg" style="zoom:54%;">
  <img src="plattegrond.jpg" class="map" usemap="#leige">
  </div>
</div>
```

NB! zoom:54% (644x702) can be changed with JS in 100% and 150%.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. You 'effectively' lose your parent div as a reference point to center the child div. I solved it by centering it upon itself. This should work:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    width = $("#container").width();
    height = $("#container").height();
    margL = $(".map").width()/2 -width/2;
    margT = $(".map").height()/2 - height/2;
    $(".map").css('margin-left',-margL)
    $(".map").css('margin-top',-margT)
})
```

This is what was done [here](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail)

Comment: Does not work. .map have to be #zoomimg to positon the div but the scrollbars are not going into the middle for scrolling left...